# How do I change the label that appears for multi-frequency recurring contributions?

Tags: civicontribute

When I activate the "Recurring" option in our Contribution Form, and select both "Monthly" and "Yearly," the generated output is a checkbox input (with id "is_recur"), followed by a label (for="is_recur"), and those are followed by a select element with options "month" and "year".  It looks like the label is supposed to automatically update wording based on the options chosen, but ours always says the same thing:  "I wish to contribute this amount every month as a recurring donation to support (organization name) year round."

I found what appears to be the source of this language in civicrm\civicrm\templates\CRM\Contribute\Form\Contribution\Confirm.tpl ... but no changes I make take effect.  Also, all of the settings in that file end at "I want to contribute this amount every month." ... so I don't know where the "... as a recurring donation to support (organization name) year round" bit is coming from.  Another developer configured CiviCRM for this client, but is no longer working with the organization, so I'm trying to get up to speed as quickly as I can.  It is possible they used a custom template to do this, but I can't even identify what file they would have modified - nor where they would have stored it - if is is a custom template.

Honestly, I'd love to just make this a static label rather than a dynamic one; if anyone can advise how to change the label to simply say, "I want to make this an automatic recurring donation (click for options).", I would GREATLY appreciate it.

Comment: Can you search your server for this bit of text: "to support (organization name) year round"? Because that's not standard and must be coming from some kind of customization.

Comment: Yes, I actually had done that before posting - using the first portion of the string was how I was able to find the .tpl file referenced in the OP.  Unfortunately, nothing turned up for the second portion.  Certainly a helpful tip though for others with a similar issue though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SE!

As @lars-sg points out, that is not standard wording.

It could come from various places:

Go to `Administer > System Settings > Directories` and note the 'Custom Template Directory'.  If that uses `[civicrm.files]`, click the help icon in the help text box to show the actual directory on your system.   Go look in the template directory and see if you have a template override with that text.

From the same page, note the extensions directory and look in there.

Also check at `Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Word Replacements` for any replacements that have been set up.

Comment: This was very helpful - thank you.  I failed to mention in the OP that this is a Wordpress site with CiviCRM installed.  Your Directories guidance made me aware that some customizations and content are stored in wp-content/uploads/, which would explain why they didn't turn up in searches of the CiviCRM plugin files.